# white space greedy regexp

Tags: regex, replace, vi

vi regex below

```
:%s/\s*/\t/g
```

replaces

```
AP DP
```

to

```
A\tP\tD\tP
```

But, I was expecting

```
AP\tDP
```

Why does this acts that?

Comment: I want to get AP\tDP.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`\s*` means match **0 or more** whitespaces greedily. If you want to replace spaces where there is **at least** one of them present, use `+` quantifier:

```
:s/\s\+/\t/g
```

Comment: You are awesome. but I had to escape '+' too. Real working regex is 's/\s\+/\t/g